# Location of Workflow Manager Database References

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, arcgis-10.6, arcgis-workflow-manager

Does anyone know where ArcCatalog references to Workflow Manager Databases are saved?

I am using Workflow Manager in a Citrix virtual desktop. Every time I restart the desktop after closing it, the reference is lost and needs to be re-created. I have not been able to locate any references in my AppData folders, where other ArcCatalog settings are stored.

I'm talking about the **Workflow Manager Databases** section of ArcCatalog's catalog tree not the **Database Connections** section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow Manager stores the information I was looking for in `C:\ProgramData\ESRI\WMX\10.6\Database`. It is possible to change this location using `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\WMX\Desktop10.6\Bin\WMXAdvancedSettings.exe`, but it requires administrative-level access.